# Stripe with Django - make form clean() method return value that isn't a form field

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-forms, stripe-payments

I am integrating Stripe payment processing into my Django app, and I can't figure out the 'correct' way to verify the customer's card information and insert a row into my Users table that contains the user's Stripe Customer ID.

Ideally, I'd love to do something along the lines of the following, in which my CheckoutForm verifies card details and raises a form ValidationError if they are incorrect. However, using this solution, I can't figure a way to get the customer.id that's generated out of the clean() function.

**forms.py**

```
class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-mail address', max_length=128, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    stripe_token = forms.CharField(label='Stripe token', widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        stripe_token = cleaned_data.get('stripe_token')
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')

        try:

            customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                email=email,
                source=stripe_token,
            )
            // I can now get a customer.id from this 'customer' variable, which I want to insert into my database

        except:
            raise forms.ValidationError("It looks like your card details are incorrect!")
```

**views.py**

```
# If the form is valid...
if form.is_valid():

    # Create a new user
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(email=form.cleaned_data['email'], stripe_customer_id=<<<I want the customer.id generated in my form's clean() method to go here>>>)
        user.save()
```

The only other solution I can think of is to run the stripe.Customer.create() function in views.py *after* the form is validated. That'll work, but it doesn't seem like the 'right' way to code things, since as I understand it all validation of form fields is supposed to be done within forms.py.

What's the proper Django coding practice in this situation? Should I just move my card validation code to views.py, or is there a cleaner way to keep the card validation code within forms.py and get the customer.id out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that *proper Django coding practice* is any different from Python coding practice in this situation. Since Django form is just a class, you can define property for `customer`. Something like this:

```
class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-mail address', max_length=128, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    stripe_token = forms.CharField(label='Stripe token', widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    _customer = None

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        stripe_token = cleaned_data.get('stripe_token')
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')  

        try:
            self.customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                email=email,
                source=stripe_token,
            )
        except:
            raise forms.ValidationError("It looks like your card details are incorrect!")

    @property
    def customer(self):
        return self._customer

    @customer.setter
    def customer(self, value):
        self._customer = value
```

Then it the `views.py` after `form.is_valid()`, you'd call this property.

```
if form.is_valid():
    customer = form.customer
```

Or maybe `@property` is an overkill and you could simply do it like this:

```
class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-mail address', max_length=128, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    stripe_token = forms.CharField(label='Stripe token', widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    customer = None

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        stripe_token = cleaned_data.get('stripe_token')
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')  

        try:
            self.customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                email=email,
                source=stripe_token,
            )
        except:
            raise forms.ValidationError("It looks like your card details are incorrect!")
```

... and still `form.customer` in `views.py`.

I guess both should work, but I haven't tested the code.

Comment: Got it — makes total sense, Borut! Thanks for the response, I've accepted this as the correct answer. One quick follow-up: would you consider it 'proper django coding practice' to include all of the form parsing logic in the clean() method? E.g., should I maybe move all of the 'user=' code block from views.py into the clean() method of forms.py?

Comment: It's a good practice to include everything related to form validation inside `clean()`. You shouldn't validate forms (or data posted by users) in views. About including `user` validation in `clean()`; I have checked a few of my projects and I haven't found many cases where I did that or made sense to me.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you for your help!